# Change font in Email

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, html-email

I need some help with sending a formatted email. Below is my code.

I want "Comments:" string to appear in bold. How to do this in vb.net or C#

```
oBLL.Comments = "Comments:" + txtComments.Text

mailBody.Append(oBLL.Comments)
```

Comment: If you are doing this as a HTML Email why not simply add <b> and </b> tags?

Comment: @user3557882 Can you please write the code. ? Where to add fontstyle ?

Comment: I don't believe you can bold the string; only the `Text` in the `txtComments` field.  But as was mentioned above, use the `<b></b>` tags in the `HTML` for the email.

Comment: @logixologist I tried that, it is not working

Comment: try this: `oBLL.Comments = "<b>Comments:</b>" + txtComments.Text`. Make sure you have set the email to be HTML email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do here is build your email body using [HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/DEFAULT.asp) syntax and set [`MailMessage.IsBodyHtml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to `true` before sending.

```
oBLL.Comments = "<strong>Comments:</strong>" + txtComments.Text;

mailBody.Append(oBLL.Comments);

// ...

// assuming mail client and message instances already exists
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
mailClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

Comment: MailMessage.IsBodyHTML = true is working but it is applying to whole email and lot other things like Environment.NewLine is not working.

Comment: @Bingit you can't be half pregnant here. Either your email is in HTML or it ain't. You can encapsulate plain text within `<pre>` and `</pre>` as a workaround.

Comment: @Bingit In HTML, `Environment.NewLine` line breaks are not rendered. Therefore, you should convert them to use HTML `<br />` (or put them inside `<pre>` tags as suggested above).